# josevalim / active_model_serializers controller argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, active-model-serializers

I am playing with Jose Valim's active_model_serializers Gem.

I am attempting to call a custom serializer in my controller, and it looks like `:json` is not using the `ActiveModel::ArraySerializer` as it should.

When I define the `default active_model_serializer` in the controller, the serializer works fine; however, when I call a custom one like this in the controller:

```
render :json => @project, :serializer => ProjectSerializer
```

I receive the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.2, and Rails 3.2.7. Any help is appreciated as I need to create a few different serializers for any given model.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that line?  The signature of `render` is `render(*args, &block)`, so even if `@project` is `nil`, you wouldn't be getting this error.  Also, what does your ProjectSerializer code look like?

Comment: If `@project` is an array, it should probably be named `@projects`. That won't fix the problem, but it would make more sense & help with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

So I must have been on crack or something. the :serializer call only accepts array's of objects.

render :json => @project, :serializer => ProjectWithTaskEstimateSerializer

When you want to call the a serializer on each object within an array of objects you need to use each_serializer. I'm not sure how I missed this.

render :json => @project, :each_serializer => ProjectSerializer

Comment: When you call render with a json array, you can use both `:serializer` and `:each_serializer` options. `:serializer` would override ArraySerializer. `:each_serializer` would override the serializer for each object in the array.